# how come the time-complexity is n log(n) instead of log (n)?

Tags: c, algorithm, time-complexity

I am wondering why this loop:

```c
for(int i = 1; i < n; i = i * 2)
    sum++;
```

has a time-complexity of `nlogn`. shouldn't it be `logn`?

`i` is increasing by powers of 2.

Comment: This loop, as given, is O(log n).  Why were you told that it's O(n * log n)?  Is this loop part of a bigger snippet of code that actually is O(n * log n)?

Comment: no this answer is from an old exam solution template. it was not part of any other code. There must have been a typo then since it should be O(log n) right?

Comment: Assuming arithmetic operations are is `O(1)`, this snippet is `O(log n)`

Comment: Maybe the examiner in question was thinking that the method implementing the ++ operation was O(n), e.g. something like  
`public int sum(int i) {
    int t = 0;
    
    while (t++ < i) {}
    
    return t;
  }`

Comment: Probably irrelevant but for the sake of completeness: `O(log n)` is a subset of `O(n log n)`. Thus, both are actually correct.